# Migration to new blog might have broken some markdown

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, blog

It seems like there may be some markdown rendering issues with old posts on the new SE blog. Specifically, at [Generalist Badge Implemented](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2010/05/generalist-badge-implemented/), there's this:

[image]

I can't find a cached version of this page anywhere, so I'm not sure what it looked like pre-migration, but I imagine Jeff would have intended those numbers to be emboldened, rather than wrapped in double-asterisks.

Comment: Original: http://i.stack.imgur.com/gU9R2.png

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's been resolved now. There's always a few breaks like this with any large import that has to be fixed manually. Thanks for catching it.